# Using https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore for a new project, is it s right appraoch, and what are the Microsoft alternatives for it

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp, pnp-js-core

We want to start a new project now we are planning to develop it using those technologies:-

1. Azure Functions
2. This library https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore

so is this a right approach to use this open source library https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore ? and what is the Microsoft provider technology which can offer similar functionalities to https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore which is not open source?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in PnP GitHub page (https://pnp.github.io/):

> **These assets are created and maintained by Microsoft & the community**
> The Community (also known as the PnP community) is an open-source initiative coordinated by Microsoft engineering.

> **PnP uses supported and recommended techniques defined by Microsoft**
> This community contributes to development documentation, samples, reusable controls, and other relevant open-source initiatives related to Microsoft 365 usage and development.

> **PnP isn't a product**
> Therefore it is not supported by official support channels. If the experienced issue(s) is caused by out-of-the-box API, it falls on the normal support patterns from Microsoft side.

PnP libraries are open source Community efforts to share reusable "tools" in order to simplify day-by-day development.

If you want a complete reference of all type of development API available on SharePoint you can check the SharePoint APIs official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index)

If you prefer not to use PnP.Core, and you are going to use only SharePoint Online, probably the most suitable options you have are:

- [SharePoint CSOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)
- [SharePoint REST API v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)
- [SharePoint REST API v2 (via Microsoft Graph)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph)

For some tasks, like one-time sites configuration, or batch activities, I often suggest PnP PowerShell Module (https://github.com/pnp/powershell).